# Hide drop down menu on start on a mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how I can hide the drop down once the website loads on a mobile phone / smart phone or when I resize the browser into a smaller window. The drop down menu I have created shows up immediately and I have to touch / click the menu button in order for it to hide.

Here is the website I have created

http://digitalspin.ph/test/manosa/campanilla-homepage/

Here is the code I have created

**HTML**

```
a#pull{
    color: #FFF;
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    width: 54%;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 67px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {  
        var pull        = $('#pull');  
            menu        = $('#menu-primary-menu');  
            menuHeight  = menu.height();  

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {  

            menu.slideToggle("");  
        });  
    });
}); 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){  
        var w = $(window).outerWidth();  
        if(w > 400 && menu.is(':hidden')) {  
            menu.removeAttr('style');  
        }  
    });   
})


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){  
        var w = $(window).outerWidth();  
        if(w > 640 && menu.is(':hidden')) {  
            menu.removeAttr('style');  
        }  
    });   
})
```

Comment: Which dropdown are you referring to? I don't see any initially when using Chrome 46.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention to view it on a mobile phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following code in your CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
    header.secondary-navigation nav ul {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

You can add a `display:none;` just after the `float:none;`.

Comment: This doesn't target the issues with the jQuery mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider this approach.

```
$(function(){
    $("#pull").click(function(){
        $("#menu-primary-menu").toggleClass("expanded");
    });
});
```

Then a little CSS to make this all work.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) {
   .menu {
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
   }
   .menu.expanded {
        height: auto;
   }
}
```

I use Media query of 736 here to target all the way up to iphone 6 +

This approach is much lighter on the phones browser and typically a bit faster for even older phones to render.

Comment: Will give it a try :)